# How to find file on NTFS volume given a volume offset

Tags: ntfs

Using a hex-editor to mount a NTFS volume, I've found an offset within the volume containing data I'm interested in. How can I figure out the full path/name of the file containing this  volume offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the [`MFT`](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-mft.htm) and parse the Data attributes for each file to find the one that includes the particular offset.

Note that you might need to look at every files stream, not only the default, so you have to parse all the Data attributes.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a quick link to the binary structure of the NTFS Data attribute. you're on your own for this one.

Comment: Drat. I was hoping there might be a tool rather than having to write the code myself. Oh, well.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there are still some people searching for the solution. There is a tool for this problem: SleuthKit Tools.

Given an byte offset from the beginning of the partition table you have to divide it by the block size of your NTFS-Partition (usually 4096).

ifind /dev/... -d block_offset => inode_number

ffind /dev/... inode_number => Location of file